# Trying to find a fix for this curvature near the top of the forehead. Any help?

Tags: mesh

Dunno what really caused it, I only tried making straight lines all together. I've highlighted the center of the curve, so I'd appreciate the help with this. (Beginner here.)

[image]

Comment: It can be a non wanted edge between two vertices, going through the top selected one to the bottom one.

Comment: Are there any ways of simply stretching one up and one down, just to align them properly? I've been trying to look for that unnecessary edge, but I fear that if I'd delete one, it would ruin the structure of the face mask.

Comment: in edit mode, progressively hide vertices around the problem to have a better vision. H key to hide, Alt+H to unhide

Comment: Oh, now I see it. Two vertices are missing, for some reason. I'm guessing that's the problem.